# AICc within SOCPROG 2.9

Tags: model-selection

My question is operational: how can I set AIC correction for small samples in SOCPROG 2.9?

I would estimate movement into and out of the study area, and residency patterns of marked individuals from a dolphin population (i.e., amount of time identified individuals resident within the study area) using lagged identification rates (LIR) in SOCPROG 2.9. Different models of no movement, emigration/mortality, and emigration + mortality (Whitehead 2001) was then fitted to the observed LIR data. Akaike’s Information Criterion was used for model selection. As AICc tend to be more accurate I would like to understand how I need to set socprog to get it.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. What is SOCPROG 2.9?

Comment: @T.E.G. There appears to be a [software manual](http://whitelab.biology.dal.ca/SOCPROG/Manual.pdf) with a similar name and author.